# Debugging drools when deployed in camel / fuseesb

Tags: apache-camel, drools, fuseesb, spring-dm

I am currently building upon the camel-drools example found here: https://github.com/FuseByExample/camel-drools-example

The route is as follows:

```
<route trace="false" id="testRoute">
    <description>Example route that will regularly create a Person with a random age and verify their age</description>
    <from uri="timer:testRoute"/>
    <bean method="createTestPerson" ref="personHelper"/>
    <to uri="drools:node1/ksession1?action=insertBody" id="AgeVerification">
        <description>valid 'action' values are:
                'execute' that takes a 'Command' object (default)
                'insertBody' that inserts the Exchange.in.body, and executes rules
                'insertMessage' that inserts the Exchange.in (type org.apache.camel.Message), and executes rules
                'insertExchange' that inserts the Exchange (type org.apache.camel.Exchange), and executes rules
            </description>
    </to>
    <choice>
        <when id="CanDrink">
            <simple>${body.canDrink}</simple>
            <log logName="Bar" message="Person ${body.name} can go to the bar"/>
        </when>
        <otherwise>
            <log logName="Home" message="Person ${body.name} is staying home"/>
        </otherwise>
    </choice>
</route>
```

I have expanded on this example for my own project and have added more complicated rules and different Facts, which I would now like to debug, however I can't figure out how to get Drools debugging working in the camel / fuse environment.

I would ideally like to see all the various debugging views that the Drools IDE provides such as the agenda view, working memory view, etc (as per http://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/5.5.0.Final/drools-expert-docs/html/ch06.html#d0e8478). I have converted my Eclipse project to a Drools project. I have created a new 'Drools application' debug configuration, but have no idea what to put in the 'main class' section. I don't have my own main class since it's camel that invokes the firing of the rules and inserting facts into the working memory.

I've tried debugging the application as a normal Java application, so I set breakpoints before  the drools part of the application is executed. I have followed the drools documentation that says that if you set normal breakpoints and click on the workingMemory variable that the drools 'Working memory' or 'Agenda' view should then populate, however I always see 'The selected working memory is empty', even though I know that it isn't. I've stepped through the code from start to finish clicking on all possible WorkingMemory variables but i still see 'the selected working memory is empty' error.

Has anyone been able to successfully debug drools when deployed using camel? If so, what steps did you take?

Cheers.

Comment: Note that there's work being done for 6.0.0-SNAPSHOT around osgi, camel and karaf improvements.

Comment: Hi, i'm not sure of the answer to this; But I'd love to see what you've done with drools :) Is it open source at all?

Answer (score 0):

I use the KnowledgeRuntimeLogger to help debug my camel/drools app.  It creates a log file that I view in the Audit view (you can drag it into the view in eclipse).

KnowledgeRuntimeLogger flogger = KnowledgeRuntimeLoggerFactory.newThreadedFileLogger(ksession,"c:/temp/wmlog");

If you need to do this in spring, you can create it as a bean with the two constructor arguments (or create you own little bean that creates the logger).

hth